# Gitlab initial commit with ignore

Tags: git

How to commit and push files from server to git on initial commit but leave out
node_modules/ on initial commit?

```
git init
git remote add origin https://xx.yy.zz/aaa/bb.git
git add .
git commit
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: don't do git add . but git add .gitignore

Comment: then edit the file?

Comment: No. I assume you already have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git init
git remote add origin ...
git add .
git reset node_modules
git commit
git push -u origin master
```

or (by adding a .gitignore file)

```
git init
git remote add origin ...
echo node_modules >> .gitignore
git add .
git commit
git push -u origin master
```